# hhvm fastcgi and apache .htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hhvm

Ok so I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^images/$ index.php?id=images [L]
```

So hhvm instead of using this rule it searches first for the images folder and looks for a index.php file

I'm using this proxy directive in the virtual host file:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/hhvm/mydomain/htdocs/$1
```

What can be done so this rule can work correctly even if the folder images exists ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried testing how mod_php acts and not using HHVM and the ProxyPassMatch directive at all? So you can see if it's something to do with the RewriteRule or the proxy rule.

Comment: With mod_php it works, when enabling HHVM with the ProxyPassMatch, that's when problems start... It probably is a ProxyPassMatch problem... I will do more tests and see exactly were the problem is I may find a solution, not sure if anyone faced this kind of problem before.

Comment: Also, is the RewriteRule being processed before the ProxyPassMatch? Not sure if this is a potential issue, but if they're in different conf files, perhaps try putting both of them in the same with the RewriteRule first.

Comment: Everything is set in the same conf file.